# Determining the Lipschitz constant

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, measure-theory

> Determine the corresponding Lipschitz constant of $f(t,y(t))=e^{(t-y)/2}$, where $D=\{(t,y) : 0\leq t \leq 1,-\infty<y<+\infty\}$.

Comment: what I did is this:
$|$f(t,y_1(t))-$f(t,y_2(t))=| e^{(t-y_1)/2}-e^{(t-y_2)/2}|=|e^{t/2}||e^{-y_1/2}.e^{-y_2/2}|$\\
how can I continue?

for the same question, I have this function $f(t,y(t))=-ty+3\frac{t}{y^2}$\\
similarly, I ended with $|t(y_2-y_1)+3t(\frac{1}{y_1^2}-\frac{1}{y_2^2})| $. Any help?

Comment: >>I have used MVT on $e^{-y_1/2}$, I got $| f(t,y_1(t))-f(t,y 2 (t))=e^{t/2}|e −y 1 /2 .e −y 2 /2 |\leq 2 e^{1/2} |y_1-y_2|$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

For the first one: $|e^{-y_1/2}.e^{-y_2/2}|$ is bounded above by 1, so $|e^{-y_1/2}.e^{-y_2/2}| \leq 1$, so $|f(t,y_1(t))-f(t,y_2(t))|=| e^{(t-y_1)/2}-e^{(t-y_2)/2}|=|e^{t/2}||e^{-y_1/2}.e^{-y_2/2}|  \leq |e^{t/2}|$. Because $0\leq t \leq 1$ it follows that $|f(t,y_1(t))-f(t,y_2(t))| \leq \sqrt{e}$.

The second one I don't think satisfies a uniform Lipschitz condition. You can calculate a Lipschitz constant via the formula:
$$\sup\limits_{D}\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|\leq L$$
where any $L$ that satisfies the formula is a Lipschitz constant. Because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -t -6\frac{t}{y^3}$ is unbounded it does not satisfy a uniform Lipschitz condition.

Comment: in the first one, I tried to use MVT:Let $(t,y_1)$ and $(t,y_2) \in D$\\
$|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|=|e^{\frac{t-y_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{t-y_2}{2}}|=|e^{\frac{t}{2}}||e^{\frac{-y_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{-y_2}{2}}|=e^{\frac{t}{2}}|e^{\frac{-y_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{-y_2}{2}}|$\\
Let $g(y)=e^{\frac{-y_1}{2}},$ then for any $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}, |e^{\frac{-y_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{-y_2}{2}}|=|g(y_1)-g(y_2)|=|g'(c)||y_1-y_2|,$ where $c$ is between $y_1$ and $y_2.$\\
Note that $|g'(c)|=|-\frac{1}{2}||e^{\frac{-c}{2}}|=\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{e^{\frac{c}{2}}}\leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{c}{2}}.$ Can you help me on how to continue

Comment: Another question: Is $f(t,y(t)=1-y^2$ lipshitz on D???   I get this:$|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|=|1-y_1^2-1+y_2^2|=|y_2^2-y_1^2|=|y_2-y_1||y_1+y_2| $  then what??

Comment: @nour I am not sure why you would use the MVT here. Again, the easiest way to check that $f(t,y(t))$ does not satisfy a uniform Lipschitz condition is by seeing that its partial derivative w.r.t. $y$ is unbounded in $D$. $$|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}| = |-2y|$$
is unbounded in the domain so it is not lipshitz

Comment: @ Teun I think I have a mistake in $f(x,y)=e^{\frac{(t-y)}{2}}$ because $|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|=e^{\frac{t}{2}}(e^{\frac{-y_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{-y_2}{2}})$ can I say that  it is bounded by 0, so the lipshitz constant is 0?

Comment: @nour You can't say the Lipshitz constant is 0 because you want to find an upper bound for $|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|$. It could only be 0 if $f(t,y)$ is a constant. The key is to realize that on the domain $e^{\frac{t}{2}}$ is bounded above by $\sqrt{e}$ when $t=1$ and $|e^{\frac{-y_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{-y_2}{2}}|$ is bounded above by 1. That's because for $y\in (-\infty,\infty)$ we have $e^{\frac{-y_1}{2}}\leq 1$ so the difference $|e^{\frac{-y_1}{2}}-e^{\frac{-y_2}{2}}|\leq 1$. Thus we can say $|f(t,y_1)-f(t,_2)|\leq |\sqrt(e) \cdot 1|$. So $\sqrt{e}$ is definitely a Lipshitz constant for $f$.

Comment: Can I say for the above question that $|-t-\frac{6t}{y}|\leq|t|+|\frac{6t}{y}| \leq 1$ in $D$?? So the Lipshitz constant is 1.

Comment: If you are talking about $f(t,y(t))=-ty+3\frac{t}{y^2}$ the derivative you gave is incorrect (I realize I also gave the wrong derivative in my original answer which I just corrected). Here $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =-t -6\frac{t}{y^3}$. Now it is true that $|-t -6\frac{t}{y^3}|\leq |t|+|6\frac{t}{y^3}|$, but if we take the point on $D$ where $t=1$ and $y=1$ we have $|t|+|6\frac{t}{y^3}|=7$ so 1 is not a correct bound. We can see that $|t|+|6\frac{t}{y^3}|$ is actually unbounded.

Comment: We can prove it's unbounded by contradiction. If we assume that $|t|+|6\frac{t}{y^3}|$ is bounded, let's say by a constant $M$, then $|t|+|6\frac{t}{y^3}| \leq M$ for all $(y,t)\in D$. Now if we choose $t =1$ and $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{M}}$ then $|t|+|6\frac{t}{y^3}| = 1 +6 M \geq M$ so $|t|+|6\frac{t}{y^3}|$ is not bounded by $M$. Because the point we choose is in $D$ for any $M$ we conclude that $|t|+|6\frac{t}{y^3}|$ is unbounded. And therefore $f(t,y) = -ty +3\frac{t}{y^2}$ is not Lipshitz